How do I tell from journald log when jenkins ran a job on a controller executor?
We've seen some instability and I just found/fixed an issue where jenkins controller had one executor.  I want to ensure jobs never run on the controller so I set the executor to 0
However, I want to go through my historical logs to see the frequency of jobs running on the controller and build history is not an option as we've already revved the environment.
So, within the system/journald logs from jenkins controller, how would I tell if jobs executed on the controller's executor?

Sadly, you can't. And Jenkins doesn't run whole jobs on executors, it runs steps. It might happen that all the steps from some job ran on a single executor, but from Jenkins perspective it's a corner case. Assigning an executor to some portion of your pipeline (which might coincide with the whole pipeline) is not recorded in the Jenkins logs, only in the job logs, as a Workspace action. You do see new agents being spun up in the Jenkins log, but I don't think even there is tells you which job triggered agent provisioning.

Thanks. We'll have to wait and see to determine the impact of going down from 1 to 0 executors on the built-in.
